# Convert json Array to Object on Vue Js 2

Tags: arrays, json, object, vuejs2

I'm trying to convert my data json from an array to an object to be able to consume the data but something went wrong...

Here is the data json sample:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "my title",
    "imgHero": "../../path/hero.jpg"
  }
]
```

And here is the Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div class="hero">
    <img :src="blog.imgHero" alt="hero image" class="heroImg">
    <h3 class="heroTitle">{{ blog.title }}</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import tripsJson from '@/data/trips.json'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    data () {
      return {
        array: tripsJson,
        blog: {}
      }
    },
    created () {
     var obj = this.array.reduce(function (acc, cur, i) {
      acc[i] = cur
      return acc
     }, {})
     this.blog = obj
     console.log(this.blog)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Any help or suggestion is more than welcome. Thx

Comment: Why dont you use v-for to loop over objects in array?

Comment: Because looping will display the entire article array and I need to consume only one article. Basically, it's a blog. when I click on the article title, it will show me a new view of the article detail

Comment: So I edited the created() method and it's working fine now. The issue now is on the console I clearly see that my array is now an object but when I data bind, blog still behave as an array. I mean to call my title for example I still need to say {{ blog[0].title }} and I wish to arrive to just {{ blog.title }}

Comment: @BeeLee Consider using a computed property, e.g. have a data field called `selectedBlog` which stores the current index of the blog you want to view in the array and then have the computed property called `currentBlog` which returns the currently selected blog in the array using that stored index. Then you can just do `currentBlog.title`.